# The service "environment.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "behatch.http_call.request"

Tags: behat

I have a problem with behatch, when I run `bin/behat` command line it shows me this error:

> The service "environment.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "behatch.http_call.request".

Comment: How did you solve this pelase?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error

```
./vendor/bin/behat  --verbose

In CheckExceptionOnInvalidReferenceBehaviorPass.php line 86:

  [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]            
  The service "environment.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "mink".
```

To solve your problem you should append your `behat.yml`. I will present three cases, maybe it can help you.

## 1 Working without mink

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    kernel: '@kernel'
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                bootstrap: features/bootstrap/bootstrap.php
                class: App\Kernel
```

## 2 Configuration when I had error

with added `Behatch\Extension` but without `Mink\Extension`

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    kernel: '@kernel'
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                bootstrap: features/bootstrap/bootstrap.php
                class: App\Kernel
        Behatch\Extension: ~
```

## 3 How I solved my problem

I added both extensions `Behatch` and `MinkExtension`.

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            contexts:
                - FeatureContext:
                    kernel: '@kernel'
                - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
                - behatch:context:browser
                - behatch:context:debug
                - behatch:context:system
                - behatch:context:json
                - behatch:context:table
                - behatch:context:rest
                - behatch:context:xml
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension:
            kernel:
                bootstrap: features/bootstrap/bootstrap.php
                class: App\Kernel
        Behatch\Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
          base_url:  'http://localhost:8000'
          sessions:
            default:
              symfony2: ~
```

Sources:

https://github.com/Behat/MinkExtension/blob/master/doc/index.rst
https://github.com/Behatch/contexts

Recommendations for solve your problem:

- 1) use `--verbose` flag
- 2) attach `behat.yml` file
- 3) attach part of composer.json with your dependencies